# No credential field in jenkins while creating job with git

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

[image]

Why there is no credential field after the Repository URL?

I tried a local jenkin install and it do ask me for the username/password.
What then I try on our remote(already setup) jenkin there is no password field.

Comment: Hey. The same problem. Did you find where it should be?

Comment: there is a version specific problem with one of the git plugin... i figured out the correct version and install that one.. and it started working fine.. sorry forgot all details

Answer (score 0):

Use the **latest version of Jenkins** to roll out this error.
I am using Jenkins-2.89.3.
Hope that helps